# What is the name of the component which looks like fuel tank pickup in Hyundai i20 diesel?

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, fuel-tank, fuel-cap

The vehicle in question is a 2016 Hyundai Elite i20 Diesel launched in India. For a petrol engine this would be the fuel pump assembly, but I couldn't find the name for the same part in diesel model. It doesn't have a fuel pump but just a filter and fuel pickup. The said component sits under the seat, and is like a cap on top of the fuel tank.

[image]

Comment: Are you wondering about the assembly? Or a single part? And realistically, I'd be surprised if there isn't a lift pump in there. EDIT: Looking at the top of it, I notice two things. First, there is only two wires going into it, which means there's no pump as you stated, but just a sending unit to measure fuel level. Second, if you clean off the tag which has a bar code on it, I'll bet the part number is there as well. This would most likely lead you to the name of the part.

Comment: Yes I am asking about the whole assembly. There is no fuel pump in there. Usually we call it a fuel pump assembly. But since there is no fuel Pump in there, what do you call it.